# mongodb in php-insert array to mongo db collection

Tags: php, mongodb, database, nosql

i use mongodb in php and have a problem to insert $subitems array to mongodb collection.

php code:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $errors = array();
    $alarm = array();

    $item_name = data::test_input($_POST["item_name"]);
    $folder_name = data::test_input($_POST["folder_name"]);
    $subitem_num = data::test_input($_POST["subitem_num"]);


    for($i=1;$i<=$subitem_num;$i++){
        ${"subitem_name$i"} = data::test_input($_POST["subitem_name".$i]);
        ${"subitem_file$i"} = data::test_input($_POST["subitem_file".$i]);
        if(count($errors)==0){
        $subitems = array(${"subitem_name$i"}=>${"subitem_file$i"});
        }
    }

    if(empty($item_name)){
        $errors['item_name']= "insert item";
    }
    if(empty($folder_name)){
        $errors['folder_name']= "insert folder";
    }
    if(count($errors)==0){
    $query = array(
        "item_name" => $item_name,
        "status" => 0,
        "folder_name" => $folder_name,
        "subitem" => $subitems
    ); 
    $result = items::insert($query);
    if($result) $alarm['success_additem'] = "submit done";
    }
}
```

i want record values to mongodb collection like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("542e71b333e916542a00002e"), "item_name" : "users management", "status" :0, "folder_name" : "users", "subitem" : { "a" : "a.php","b" : "b.php" },"c" : "c.php" }
```

how to write php code for insert to mongodb collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your problem is that the `subitem` field in your document never contains more than a single key/value pair when inserted into the database.

```
for($i=1;$i<=$subitem_num;$i++){
    ${"subitem_name$i"} = data::test_input($_POST["subitem_name".$i]);
    ${"subitem_file$i"} = data::test_input($_POST["subitem_file".$i]);
    if(count($errors)==0){
    $subitems = array(${"subitem_name$i"}=>${"subitem_file$i"});
    }
}
```

Based on that `for` loop, you're over-writing `$subitems` in each iteration. I assume you mean to assign a key within it, in which case you'd be better served with the following:

```
$subitems = array();

for($i = 1; $i <= $subitem_num; $i++) {
    $key = data::test_input($_POST["subitem_name".$i]);
    $value = data::test_input($_POST["subitem_file".$i]);

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $subitems[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

For the record, I have no idea why you're checking `$errors` here, as it's assigned once at the top of this function and doesn't appear to be modified within the `for` loop; however, I left it in place so it lines up with the original example you've provided.

Also, there is really no reason to use dynamically-named variables here. Fixed terms such as `$key` and `$value` make the code much more readable.